# I'm unable to push changes that i made using github on heroku

Tags: python, github, heroku

I created a telegram python bot using github and deployed it on heroku. After deployment i made few changes on GitHub and did manual deploy and it was working all fine. But when today i made one changes and trying to do manual deploy, it is showing an error. I don't know what to do. Please help.
Here are the logs

````
Activity Feed  Build LogID 08be3020-bb55-485e-b463-ed95b0d3d1dd
-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
-----> Using buildpacks:
       1. https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python
       2. https://github.com/jonathanong/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg-latest
-----> Python app detected
-----> Using Python version specified in runtime.txt
-----> Python version has changed from python-3.9.7 to python-3.9.13, clearing cache
-----> No change in requirements detected, installing from cache
-----> Installing python-3.9.13
-----> Installing pip 22.1.2, setuptools 60.10.0 and wheel 0.37.1
-----> Installing SQLite3
-----> Installing requirements with pip
       Collecting git+https://github.com/starry69/python-markdown2.git (from -r /tmp/build_21dd5c41/requirements.txt (line 33))
         Cloning https://github.com/starry69/python-markdown2.git to /tmp/pip-req-build-saxp1xzv
         Running command git clone --filter=blob:none --quiet https://github.com/starry69/python-markdown2.git /tmp/pip-req-build-saxp1xzv
         fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address
         error: subprocess-exited-with-error
         
         × git clone --filter=blob:none --quiet https://github.com/starry69/python-markdown2.git /tmp/pip-req-build-saxp1xzv did not run successfully.
         │ exit code: 128
         ╰─> See above for output.
         
         note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
       error: subprocess-exited-with-error
       
       × git clone --filter=blob:none --quiet https://github.com/starry69/python-markdown2.git /tmp/pip-req-build-saxp1xzv did not run successfully.
       │ exit code: 128
       ╰─> See above for output.
       
       note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
 !     Push failed```
````